# How to put a threshold in a DensityPlot?

Tags: plotting

I've a function of two variables f(x, y) which assumes values between 0 and 1 only in a certain region of the domain of the R^2 space, i.e.

x ∈ (1, 2)

y ∈ (0, x/2)

I'm interested in a heatmap/density-plot, thus I'm doing

```
DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, 1, 2}, {y, 0, 1}, 
            ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", Frame -> True, 
            FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
            PlotLegends -> BarLegend[All, LegendLabel -> "Frequency"]]
```

How could I

- exclude from the density map those values not in the [0, 1] range, or
- shadow the plot area where f(x, y) is not between 0 and 1 ?

Thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: Look up `PlotRange` and `ClippingStyle`.

Comment: The option `PlotRange->{0,1}' will clip your z-values, and you can format the style of the clipping with 'ClippingStyle->"Whatever you want"`. I can't tell if this is what you want, or @Chip Hurst's answer.

Comment: Thank you, @N.J.Evans !! I'm accepting Chip Hurst's answer but your comment will help a lot as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the sole purpose of `RegionFunction`:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[10 x + 10 y], {x, 1, 2}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[All, LegendLabel -> "Frequency"], 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 0 < y < x/2]
]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Another way in V10 is

```
R = Polygon[{{1, 0}, {1, 0.5}, {2, 1}, {2, 0}}];

DensityPlot[Sin[10 x + 10 y], {x, y} ∈ R, 
  ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[All, LegendLabel -> "Frequency"], 
  PlotPoints -> 40
]
```

Comment: A big "thank you", @Chip Hurst !!! That's exactly what I was looking for.